# Check if JSON contains a property

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

I am reading [microsoft docs ms sql JSON options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-modify-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)
And I would like to check if my column `Settings` which is nvarchar, I put there some JSON, and if that JSON contains property `name`.

Is it doable?

something like:

```sql
DECLARE @info NVARCHAR(100)='{"name":"John","skills":["C#","SQL"]}'
IF (ISJSON(@info) > 0)  
BEGIN  
     -- if (@info contains `$.name`) 
     --begin
        -- SET @info=JSON_MODIFY(@info,'$.name','Mike')
     --end
     -- else 
     --begin
       --  SET @info=JSON_MODIFY(@info,'$.name','Mike')
     --end
END
```

I need to check if that JSON property exists, if exists then just update value, if not then insert that property with predefined value.

Comment: SSMS is just a client tool. It doesn't affect how the query runs and the latest version is 18.2. I suspect you meant SQL Server 2017?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, so? I didnt mention ssms?

Comment: As for checking and modifying, you'd do it the same way you'd update any other data - not with an `IF` but a condition in `WHERE`. If you want to check for the existence of a specific property you don't need to use ISJSON first. Use `JSON_VALUE` and check its return value

Comment: You used the SSMS, SSMS-2017 tags which I removed.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**How to insert or update `key: value` pair:**

If you want to *" ... check if that JSON property exists, if exists then just update value, if not then insert that property with predefined value ..."*, the [remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-modify-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#remarks) section from the `JSON_MODIFY` documentation gives you one possible solution:

> The JSON_MODIFY function lets you either update the value of an
> existing property, insert a new key:value pair, or delete a key based
> on a combination of modes and provided values.

If you execute `JSON_MODIFY` with not `NULL` value, in `lax` mode, the function will try to:

- insert a new `key:value` pair if the specified `path` doesn't exist.
- update the existing `key: value` pair if the specified `path` exists.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE #Data (
   Settings nvarchar(100)
)
INSERT INTO #Data
   (Settings)
VALUES
   (N'{"name":"John","skills":["C#","SQL"]}')
```

Statement:

```
-- Update existing key
UPDATE #Data
SET Settings = JSON_MODIFY(Settings, 'lax $.name', 'Mike')
WHERE ISJSON(Settings) = 1

-- Insert new key
UPDATE #Data
SET Settings = JSON_MODIFY(Settings, 'lax $.day', 'Sunday')
WHERE ISJSON(Settings) = 1
```

Output:

```
SELECT *
FROM #Data

Settings
{"name":"Mike","skills":["C#","SQL"],"day":"Sunday"}
```

**How to check for specific `key` or `value`:**

If you want to check if specific `key` exists, use `OPENJSON()`:

```
SELECT *
FROM #Data d
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(d.Settings) j
WHERE j.[key] = 'name'
```

If you want to check if specific `value` exists, use `JSON_VALUE()`:

```
SELECT *
FROM #Data
WHERE JSON_VALUE(Settings, '$.name') = 'Mike'
```

Example with the statement from the question:

```
DECLARE @info NVARCHAR(100)='{"name":"John","skills":["C#","SQL"]}'
IF (ISJSON(@info) > 0)  BEGIN  
   IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM OPENJSON(@info) WHERE [key] = 'name') PRINT 'Yes'
   ELSE PRINT 'No'
END
```

**New JSON features in SQL Server 2022:**

Starting from SQL Server 2022, you may use `JSON_PATH_EXISTS()` function to check whether a specified JSON path exists:

```
DECLARE @info NVARCHAR(100)='{"name":"John","skills":["C#","SQL"]}'
IF ISJSON(@info) = 1 BEGIN  
   IF JSON_PATH_EXISTS(@info, '$.name') = 1 PRINT 'Yes'
   ELSE PRINT 'No'
END
```

Comment: you checking ISJSON formatted as JSON, but how can I check if already exists property `name` in JSON? I dont want to insert another property `name` if one elaready exists.

Comment: @Stefan0309 `JSON_MODIFY` will not append another `name` property in the JSON text. It will overwrite the value, if the key exists, or append a new key with the new value.

Comment: That helped me a lot! To run version with OPENJSON I needed to increase compatibility_level of DB by running "ALTER DATABASE "db-name"
SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 130;" in mssms